# Is it possible to create instance in C++ program of a class defined in Python module?

Tags: c++, boost-python

What I'm trying to do is create a virtual class (ClassTest) in a C++ program, then import it in Python script, create derived class in that script and then import that derived class back in C++.

Here's the code that I came up with so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

using namespace boost::python;
using namespace std;

class ClassTest {
public:
    ClassTest () {}

    virtual int someFunction () = 0;
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(ClassTest) {
    class_< ClassTest, boost::noncopyable >("ClassTest", no_init)
        .def("someFunction", &ClassTest::someFunction)
    ;
}

int main() {
    try {

        Py_Initialize();

        initClassTest();

        ClassTest* testObject = **???**

        cout << "Function result = " << testObject.someFunction() << endl;

        Py_Finalize();

    } catch (error_already_set& e) {

        PyErr_PrintEx(0);
        return 1;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

And there's Python script:

```
import ClassTest

class classTestChild(ClassTest.ClassTest):
    def someFunction ():
        return 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete example how this can be done. You need a wrapper class so that virtual functions can be overridden in Python.

ClassTest.h:

```
class ClassTest 
{
public:
    virtual ~ClassTest(){}

    virtual int someFunction () = 0;
};
```

ClassTest.cpp (must be built into .so/.dll):

```
class ClassTestWrap : public ClassTest, public python::wrapper<ClassTest>
{
public:
    virtual int someFunction() override
    {
        if (python::override f = this->get_override("someFunction"))
            return f();
        return ClassTestWrap::someFunction();
    }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(ClassTest)
{
    python::class_< ClassTestWrap, boost::noncopyable >("ClassTest")
    .def("someFunction", python::pure_virtual(&ClassTestWrap::someFunction));
}
```

main.cpp (executable):

```
try
{
    Py_Initialize();
    python::object main = python::import("__main__");
    python::object global(main.attr("__dict__"));
    python::object ignored = python::exec("import ClassTest\n"
                                          "class classTestChild(ClassTest.ClassTest):\n"
                                          "    def someFunction(self):\n"
                                          "        return 4\n"
                                          "\n"
                                          "child = classTestChild()", global);
    ClassTest *obj = python::extract<ClassTest*>(global["child"]);
    int value = obj->someFunction();
    printf("value = %d\n", value);
    Py_Finalize();
}
catch (python::error_already_set&)
{
    PyErr_Print();
    PyErr_Clear();
}
```

And the output:

```
value = 4
```

This example will work if ClassTest.so/ClassTest.dll and .exe are in the same folder and .exe is being called from the same folder (./test.exe)

Comment: Got an error:

"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named ClassTest"

I tried something else, and got error "NameError: name 'ClassTestChild' is not defined", you can see my code here: http://pastebin.com/vp3S3mqR

Comment: I updated my answer, you need to build python module into .so/.dll and test program into .exe

Comment: Hmm, I added initClassTest(); after Py_Initialize(); and got another error: "RuntimeError: This class cannot be instantiated from Python".

Why to .so? Shouldn't that be no different from just compiling and running it statically?

Comment: You need to build it into `ClassTest.so` so that `import ClassTest` will work.

Comment: But it's working and importing, it just cannot make an instance of that python class. For simple functions it works very well, it just doesn't with classes.

Comment: Then copy content of `ClassTest.cpp` file there and check. You need a wrapper class so that virtual functions can be overridden in Python

Comment: When you add initClassTest(); after Py_Initialize(); it works without compilation to .so. But now if someFunction (defined in python) is longer than 1 line it gives an error "IndentationError: unexpected indent". But if I add helper someFunctionImpl(), then I can write more than 1 line...
http://pastebin.com/iZQYXFTK - this works. Add any line before "return someFunctionImpl()" and it crashes...

Comment: Okay, i had some tabs instead of spaces in my python code, don't worry about sentences other than first in above comment